# list index out of range - De Fortran para Python

Tags: python, fortran

Eu escrevi um programa em Fortran e agora estou tentando escrevê-lo em Python. Contudo, está dando um erro:

> D[i][j+1] = - u_med[i+1]/(delta_r[i]*delta_r[i+1])
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

Sou iniciante em Python, o que pode está dando errado? Este é o código:

```
D = []
u_med = []
delta_r = []
for i in range(2,n):
  for j in range(2,n):
    if i == j:
      D[i][j+1] = - u_med[i+1]/(delta_r[i]*delta_r[i+1])
      t1 = u_med[i+1]/(delta_r[i]*delta_r[i])
      t2 = u_med[i]/(delta_r[i]*delta_r[i])
      D[i][j]= t1 + t2 + V[i]
      D[i+1][j]= - u_med[i+1]/(delta_r[i]*delta_r[i+1])

t1 = u_med[2]/(delta_r[1]*delta_r[1])
t2 = 0
D[1][1]= t1 + t2 + V[1]
D[1][2]= - u_med[2]/(delta_r[1]*delta_r[2])
D[2,1]= - u_med[2]/(delta_r[2]*delta_r[1])
t1 = 0
t2 = u_med[n]/(delta_r[n]*delta_r[n])

D[n][n]= t1 + t2 + V[n]
```

Edit: Eu estou trabalhando com a equação de Schrödinger unidimensional num grid variável... Enfim, estou tetando escrevê-la na forma matricial, com uma matriz N x N tridiagonal simétrica.

Mesmo código no Fortran:

```
do i=2,n-1
do j=2,n-1

if (i.eq.j) then

D(i,j+1)=-u_med(i+1)/(delta_r(i)*delta_r(i+1))
t1 =u_med(i+1)/(delta_r(i)*delta_r(i))
t2 = u_med(i)/(delta_r(i)*delta_r(i))
D(i,j)= t1 + t2 + V(i)
D(i+1,j)=-u_med(i+1)/(delta_r(i)*delta_r(i+1))

end if

end do
end do

t1 =u_med(2)/(delta_r(1)*delta_r(1))
t2 = 0.d0

D(1,1)= t1 + t2 + V(1)
D(1,2)= -u_med(2)/(delta_r(1)*delta_r(2))
D(2,1)= -u_med(2)/(delta_r(2)*delta_r(1))

t1 =0.d0
t2 = u_med(n)/(delta_r(n)*delta_r(n))

D(n,n)= t1 + t2 + V(n)
```

Comment: Todas as suas listas estão vazias, então nenhum índice que utilizou existirá. O que exatamente precisa fazer? Pode descrever com palavras, editando a pergunta?

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela resposta, mas não entendi.. Como assim todas as listas estão vazias? Em Python eu num primeiro preciso criar um vetor vazio, para então adicionar a informação no loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veja um trecho do seu código com alguns comentários:

```
  1 D = []                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  2 #    ↳ Aqui você definiu D como uma lista vazia                                                                                                                                                                              
  3                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  4 u_med = []                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  5 #        ↳ Aqui você definiu u_med como uma lista vazia                                                                                                                                                                      
  6                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  7 delta_r = []                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  8 #          ↳ Aqui você definiu delta_r como uma lista vazia                                                                                                                                                                  
  9                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 10 #                  ↱ Aqui você utilizou n que não está definido                                                                                                                                                              
 11 for i in range(2, n):                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 12     for j in range(2, n):                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 13     ┆   if i == j:                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 14     ┆   ┆   D[i][j+1] = - u_med[i+1]/(delta_r[i]*delta_r[i+1])                                                                                                                                                               
 15     ┆   ┆   #   |             |            |         ↳ Aqui você está acessando a posição i+1 de uma lista vazia                                                                                                             
 16     ┆   ┆   #   |             |            ↳ Aqui você está acessando a posição i de uma lista vazia                                                                                                                         
 17     ┆   ┆   #   |             ↳ Aqui você está acessando a posição i+1 de uma lista vazia                                                                                                                                    
 18     ┆   ┆   #   ↳ Aqui você está tentando definir o valor da posição i, j+1 de uma lista vazia                                                                                                                               
 19     ┆   ┆   t1 = u_med[i+1]/(delta_r[i]*delta_r[i])                                                                                                                                                                          
 20     ┆   ┆   t2 = u_med[i]/(delta_r[i]*delta_r[i])                                                                                                                                                                            
 21     ┆   ┆   D[i][j]= t1 + t2 + V[i]                                                                                                                                                                                          
 22     ┆   ┆   D[i+1][j]= - u_med[i+1]/(delta_r[i]*delta_r[i+1])
```

O erro acontece na linha 14 justamente por tentar acessar valores em listas vazias, isso considerando que o objeto `n` esteja devidamente definido no seu código e apenas não postou na pergunta.

Como não faz sentido acessar valores de listas vazias, não há como inferir o que desejas fazer, por isso solicitei no [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/293314/list-index-out-of-range-de-fortran-para-python?noredirect=1#comment596290_293314) que descrevesse, em palavras, qual o objetivo do código. Sem a descrição, não tem como te ajudar além disso.

Comment: Tudo bem, as informações prestadas foram muito úteis. Muito obrigado. Acabei conseguindo resolver o problema. Como se trata da construção de uma matriz tridiagonal, acabei por utilizar o np.zeros(n,2) para a lista em questão.