# IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2

Tags: python

> ```
> D[i][j+1] = - u_med[i+1]/(delta_r[i]*delta_r[i+1])
> ```
>
> IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2

Já tive outro problema com esse código e perguntei [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/293314/list-index-out-of-range-de-fortran-para-python), mas o problema agora é este.

Eu estou trabalhando com a equação de Schrödinger unidimensional num grid variável... Então estou tetando escrevê-la na forma matricial, com uma matriz N x N tridiagonal simétrica.

Tentei utilizar np.zeros pois antes estava dando outro erro porque eu estava tentando acessar valores em listas vazias.

Quando tento escrever np.zeros((n,n)), dá o seguinte erro:

> ```
> D[i][j+1] = - u_med[i+1]/(delta_r[i]*delta_r[i+1])
> ```
>
> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Como posso reverter isso?

```
n = 51
D = np.zeros((n,2))
for i in range(2,n):
  for j in range(2,n):
    if i == j:
      D[i][j+1] = - u_med[i+1]/(delta_r[i]*delta_r[i+1])
      t1 = u_med[i+1]/(delta_r[i]*delta_r[i])
      t2 = u_med[i]/(delta_r[i]*delta_r[i])
      D[i][j]= t1 + t2 + V[i]
      D[i+1][j]= - u_med[i+1]/(delta_r[i]*delta_r[i+1])
```

Comment: Pelo erro, você está acessando o índice 3 de uma sequência que só possui 2 elementos.

Comment: Olá, obrigado por responder mais uma vez. Mas quanto ao segundo caso.. Quando tento escrever np.zeros((n,n)), dá o seguinte erro:

D[i][j+1] = - u_med[i+1]/(delta_r[i]*delta_r[i+1])
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: Rapaz, esse erro acontece quando você acessa o índice 3 de uma sequência que só possui 2 elementos. Abs!